# GeoFire Query didn't return result

Tags: ios, firebase, geofire

I have a list of stores as below:

```
"store" : {
"2" : {
"address" : "amman",
"ctime" : "17:05:00",
"g" : "9q8yyxfgs8",
"id" : "11",
"l" : [ 31.9453666, 35.9283716 ],
"name" : "Kaluti",
"otime" : "00:00:00",
"phone" : "0795080034",
"userId" : "4"
},
"7" : {
"address" : "amman",
"ctime" : "01:00:00",
"g" : "9q8yyxfgs8",
"id" : "7",
"l" : [ 31.9453666, 35.9283716 ],
"name" : "Zalloum33",
"otime" : "05:00:00",
"phone" : "0795080034",
"userId" : "2"
},
"11" : {
"address" : "amman",
"ctime" : "17:05:00",
"g" : "9q8yyxfgs8",
"id" : "11",
"l" : [ 31.9453666, 35.9283716 ],
"name" : "Kaluti",
"otime" : "00:00:00",
"phone" : "0795080034",
"userId" : "4"
},
"12" : {
"address" : "asd",
"ctime" : "22:00:00",
"g" : "9q8yyxfgs8",
"id" : "12",
"l" : [ 37.7922, -122.4056973 ],
"name" : "Amam",
"otime" : "10:00:00",
"phone" : "0795126776",
"userId" : "4"
},
"19" : {
".priority" : "9q8yyxfgs8",
"g" : "9q8yyxfgs8",
"id" : "10",
"l" : [ 37.7922, -122.4056973 ],
"name" : "ahmad"
}
}
```

when I try to fetch this location with this code the query didn't return any value

```
let center = CLLocation(latitude: 31.97375, longitude: 35.872316)

if let circleQuery = geoFire?.query(at: center, withRadius: 1.0) {
    _ = circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered) { (key, location) in
        print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
    }

    circleQuery.observeReady{
        print("All initial data has been loaded and events have been fired for circle query!")
    }
}
```

but if I try to use the same code and just change the CLLocation with

```
let center = CLLocation(latitude: 37.7832889, longitude: -122.4056973)
```

it's return data.

please advice me where's the problem??

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the radius according to your needs. In your example you have a radius of 1.0 metres, which will only return the objects within 1 meter distance to your center location. Try increasing it to 500.0 metres like I've done in the example below:

```
let center = CLLocation(latitude: 31.97375, longitude: 35.872316)

if let circleQuery = geoFire?.query(at: center, withRadius: 500.0) {
    _ = circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered) { (key, location) in
        print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
    }

    circleQuery.observeReady{
        print("All initial data has been loaded and events have been fired for circle query!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried it as you sent but I still have the same problem

Comment: @Alkalouti if you use " let center = CLLocation(latitude: 31.9453666 , longitude: 35.9283716) " do you get three results?

Comment: No, I didn't get any result but if I add let center = CLLocation(latitude: 37.7832889, longitude: -122.4056973) it returns two result